# How to cast to an unknown Type, need to cast to a GenericType, but T is unknown

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, casting

I need to call the method DeepClone() from an object that I don't know the type.

```
object x = GetObject();
var x2 = x as IDeepCloneable< ?????? >;//What can I do here???
var clone = x2.DeepClone();

public interface IDeepCloneable<T>
{
    T DeepClone();
}
```

---

I have tried to create a new "base" interface and add ": IDeepCloneable" to the generic class.

```
public interface IDeepCloneable
{
   object DeepClone();
}
```

but in this case I need to change the method of the derived interface from T DeepClone(); to new T DeepClone();. As a result, all the classes that already implement IDeepCloneable< T> will not compile..

Comment: If you're in .NET 4.0 you can just use `dynamic` for this

Comment: @Servy I've done it... also you can use [Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) here as well... It will allow you to make a specialization of the generic at runtime and assign it to a dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a covariant interface:

```
public interface IDeepCloneable<out T>
{
    T DeepClone();
}
```

You can then cast to `IDeepCloneable<object>`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something. Your answer is not clear to me. Compile error: The type 'object' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'My.IDeepCloneable<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'object' to 'My.IDeepCloneable<object>'

Comment: Because object is not `IDeepCloneable` - you have to implement the interface on objects that you want to be deep cloneable

Comment: Using your original example, he means you could do something like:

var x = GetObject() as IDeepCloneable<object>;
var clone = x.DeepClone();

...assuming `x` has a runtime type of some type of the form `IDeepCloneable<?>`.

Comment: but "as IDeepCloneable<object>" is not compiling

Comment: A couple points: (1) the `where T : IDeepCloneable<T>` constraint does not seem necessary, and the example should work if you omit it; (2) this will not work if the runtime type of `T` is a value type (struct).  In other words, if `x` has a runtime type of `struct MyCloneable : IDeepCloneable<MyCloneable> { ... }`, you cannot cast `x` to `IDeepCloneable<object>`.

Comment: @SLaks, please correct your code as Mike Strobel's has pointed out. It works!

Answer (score 2):

In C# 4.0 the `dynamic` keyword allows you to work around this by suspending type checking until runtime:

```
dynamic x = GetObject();
var clone = x.DeepClone();
```

Will work fine insofar as there is a method `DeepClone()` on `x`

Comment: There's really nothing gained here over just having `DeepClone` return `object`.  Using a non-generic interface even gives you greater compile time type safety than this does, without restricting any functionality that is needed.

Comment: This does not suspend type checking; it causes the member binding to be deferred until runtime.  The binding will be applied using the same rules as would normally be enforced at compile time.  The key difference is that the member will be bound against the runtime type of `x`, which is not known at compile time, and in fact it may be bound several times if the code is invoked for different runtime types of `x`.

Comment: @Servy What you gain here is the fact you may not know what `T` is, like I said... I've had to do this before on types generated at runtime, it's not fun but it works.

Comment: @MikeStrobel that sounds a lot like suspending type checking at compile time to me....

Comment: @Mgetz Which is why I said that it gains nothing over using the *non-generic* interface.  If you use a non-generic interface then you don't have a `T` that you need to know the type of.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0 but I'm getting this error: "Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported"

Comment: @Pedro77 are you referencing `Microsoft.CSharp`?

Comment: @Mgetz Yes, if you actually qualify the statement with "at compile time".  The way your answer is phrased, I read it as "type checking is disabled" as opposed to "type checking is *deferred*".  It is a common misconception that `dynamic` magically waives strong typing, which (in the absence of custom binding) it does not.

Comment: @Mgetz Seems like it is here, based on the question.